# Order result from a query SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I try to get from a database the results in a specific order.

Let say I have a table called "books"
3 columns : Id, Title, Price

The python code to get all information will be :

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `books`""")
```

Now I want to order it by Title ASC I should right

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY Title ASC""")
```

How may I do the same with a variable.
The user tells me the column need for example Price
I though about

```
sort = 'Price'
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY ? ASC""", (sort,))
```

But it doesn't work.
How to also do the same with ASC and DESC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have no problem using `format()`

```
query = """SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY {} ASC""".format('Price')
cursor.execute(query)
```

If you want to include the 'desc' and asc just do:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY {} {} """.format('Price', 'DESC')
cursor.execute(query)
```

Here's a [summary](https://pyformat.info/) of how to do basic formatting.

Comment: Thank you, that works.
I read your website, that's clear.
Just curious why it doesn't work with my example ?

Comment: I don't think that's native to python.